# Using sum and datediff from 2 tables

Tags: sum, date-math

I am using 2 tables

Members       (MemberID, MemberName, Department, JoinDate, LeaveDate)
Subscriptions (ID, MemberName, DatePaid, AmountPaid)
I have combined them

SELECT Members.MemberID,
Members.MemberName,
Members.Department,
Members.JoinDate,
Members.LeaveDate,
Subscriptions.MemberName,
Subscriptions.DatePaid
FROM Subscriptions
LEFT JOIN Members ON Subscriptions.MemberName = Members.MemberName
I am trying to add a column to calculate the number of weeks - DateDiff(JoinDate,CurDate()) as Weeks and also Sum(Subscriptions.AmountPaid)

Can do individual, but want in same table

myphpadmin -Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.11PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation sodium Documentation PHP version: 8.2.11 –

Answer (score 2):

Try this query, it combines data from the "Members" and "Subscriptions" tables, calculating two additional columns: "Weeks" (number of weeks since joining) and "TotalAmountPaid" (sum of subscription payments). It groups the results by member, ensuring no duplicates, effectively presenting a unified table with all required information.

```
SELECT
    Members.MemberID,
    Members.MemberName,
    Members.Department,
    Members.JoinDate,
    Members.LeaveDate,
    Subscriptions.DatePaid,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), Members.JoinDate) as Weeks,
    SUM(Subscriptions.AmountPaid) as TotalAmountPaid
FROM Members
LEFT JOIN Subscriptions ON Members.MemberName = Subscriptions.MemberName
GROUP BY Members.MemberID;
```